# Active directory 2012 password policy

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, password, password-reset, password-policy

I have a windows server 2012 R2 active directory environment running in my office. I have a primary domain and a child domain. Both the domains have password complexity enabled. Active directory admins are able to change the password for the users. When users try to change passwords on there laptop using ctrl+alt+del they get a password complexity error. More over, when I tried to change the password on my laptop, it let me change the password once, then it stopped working all of a sudden. please advise what might be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second change issue...
What is the domain policy setting for "minimum password age"? If that is a non zero number, you need to wait that time period before another change is allowed.

You can find that info with powershell command `Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` or by looking in the Default Domain Policy at the path: Windows Settings/Security Settings/Account Policies/Password Policy.

Comment: The minimum password age was set to 1 and that created as we tried to change password the same day. It is now fixed. Thanks for your help.